# Sublime text permissions not enough

Tags: ubuntu, sublime-text

I have a problem according to which I cannot install new packages through `package control`, my workspace always reset on load and etc. If I open sublime throught console `sudo subl` then these issues are solved.

What can I do, to solve that kind of behavior?

*Recently I worked with elementary os and I haven't found this problem there.

*I use now ubuntu 15.04

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you used `sudo` to open Sublime the first time, so your `~/.config/sublime-text-3` directory (or `~/.config/sublime-text-2`, you don't say which version you're using) is owned by `root`, so your regular user doesn't have write access to it. You'll have to change the permissions by using [`chown`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/chown). First, change to your home directory:

```
cd
```

Then run `chown`, replacing `username` with your actual user name, and `X` with either `2` or `3`, depending on which version of Sublime you're using:

```
sudo chown -R username .config/sublime-text-X
```

Finally, for those times when you *do* need to open Sublime as `root`, first login as `root`:

```
sudo su -
```

Then open Sublime:

```
subl
```

This will be a completely clean version, unrelated to the install in your home directory. I'd recommend **not** installing Package Control and plugins to avoid any security holes, but it's up to you. Once you're done, close Sublime and log out as `root` by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> in Terminal, or just typing `logout`.

Now, for editing regular files as your regular user, you can just run

```
subl filename
```

and you should be able to use Package Control just fine. For editing system files, running

```
sudo subl filename
```

will open a new instance of Sublime with superuser privileges, so be careful what you do!